# Pop out spark plug: Can drive to the garage?

Tags: car, sparkplugs

I have a Dodge Caravan 2008 3.3L and the ceramic of one spark plug break and pop out leaving the hole free in the cylinder. I want to get my car to the garage near ( 7-8km ). When I start the engine I can hear the air/gas mixture forced through the hole and the car don't the same power as useall. It's smell gasoline a bit too.

I can drive to the garage like that or need to be tow?

Comment: have it towed..

Comment: Agreed, have it towed, or get a friend to fit a replacement spark plug if you can't.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just get the tiny new spark plug and tighten it down then trying to move the large car to the spark plug?

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen What?

Comment: I mean go to garage and get a new spark plug and install it. Then you can drive the car. It would be cheapest option, but of course if you can get it towed for free then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen How can you install it when the old one is snapped in two and part of it is still in the cylinder head?

Comment: Well, you wrote that the ceramic part got broken, it is difficult to assess your situation without a photo. The plug is unscrewed using a socket wrench. So you can just pull it out after unscrewing it. The ceramic part has relevance, it is only an insulator for the electrical connection. See http://auto.howstuffworks.com/under-the-hood/vehicle-maintenance/change-auto-spark-plugs1.htm Out of curiosity, how did it get broken?

Answer (score 2):

Do not drive the car.

The reason you can smell gasoline is because unburnt fuel is escaping through the hole.

If enough fuel air mix collects under your hood and it finds a spark or ignition source, you risk a fire under your bonnet.

Because it will be in vapour form if it does ignite you can reasonably expect a fireball, followed by the car catching fire.

Dont do it. Its not worth the risk.

Other options are:

1. Get it towed.
2. Get a mechanic to come to you.
3. Replace the spark plug yourself or ask a friend to help.

If you have to pay to get it towed, calling a mobile mechanic to come to you may cost less.

Comment: ...or unplug the wiring to the fuel injector on the affected cylinder?

Comment: Perhaps if you have no other choice. Because it will suck in some dust also. Air will flow into manifold from the opening with least resistance bypassing the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Get the vehicle picked up or towed to a garage.

If you're lucky the whole ceramic and electrode part of the plug will have blown out leaving just the thread. Hopefully nothing has dropped into the cylinder as this can cause a lot of damage.

The garage will need to remove the remaining spark plug threads from the cylinder head.. Hopefully they'll come out easily.. However do be prepared as sometimes the threads are seized into the cylinder head and it may be necessary to remove the cyl head to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to drive it be sure to disconnect the fuel injector wiring harness for that cylinder (if equipped).

This will prevent fuel from venting into the immediate vicinity of the hot engine.

Comment: ... disconnect the WIRE HARNESS CONNECTION to the fuel injector for that cylinder... if so equipped.